# Передать значение переменной из js в js

Tags: javascript

Задача состоит в том, чтобы передать значение переменной category

```
$(function() {
    var filter = $("[data-filter]");
    filter.on("click", function(event) {
    var category = $(this).data('filter');
        window.location.href = 'products.html';
    });
});
```

в js скрипт для html страницы, загружаемой по клику:

```
$(function() {
 $("[data-cat]").each(function() {
     prodCat = $(this).data('cat');
     if(prodCat.indexOf(category) == -1){
        $(this).addClass('hide');
     } else {
        $(this).removeClass('hide');
     }
 });
});
```

Comment: в данном случае только с помощью get параметра либо hash параметра

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться:)

Comment: можно начать творить дичь и передавать через куки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

самое удобное это через localStorage/sessionStorage - нет лишнего в запросе и в отличие от куки не отправляется на сервер

```
$(function() {
    var filter = $("[data-filter]");
    filter.on("click", function(event) {
        var category = $(this).data('filter');
        sessionStorage.setItem('cat', category);
        window.location.href = 'products.html';
    });
});
```

а во втором месте var category = sessionStorage.getItem('cat');

Comment: Спасибо большое:) Работает